# Simple Stripe Checkout - No button appearing on redirect page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, stripe.net

I'm having a strange issue where the page my customer is redirected to after a successful purchase, an upsell page which is supposed to have another Stripe Checkout button, does not have the intended button (so the upsell won't work). Here's what's supposed to happen:

- Customer clicks the  blue button on this page to buy a CD ( http://www.radionowhere.net/kit/ )
- Stripe purchase process goes as intended and redirects buyer to this page ( http://www.radionowhere.net/up/ )
- Customer sees 2nd blue button and clicks to purchase upsell

What's actually happening is that Stripe is redirecting the post-purchase customer to a page with a different URL - http://www.radionowhere.net/up/?payment=success&amount=1000 - and this URL is not generating the button from the shortcode.

If anyone could help me figure out the problem, so that http://www.radionowhere.net/up/?payment=success&amount=1000 displays the correct blue button as intended, I'd truly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide more insight of your code. like the code for the page after successful payment

Comment: Thanks! Well, i tried to paste it in here, but it's too long. Maybe just go to the page and view source?

Comment: i was talking about the php code. m not sure viewing source will help

Comment: Not sure what you mean about php. There's wordpress php code, and the Stripe button is generated by a wordpress plugin. Sorry - don't know much about php.

Comment: sorry to say, but cant help u much unless I have something to look into

Comment: Anyone else with an idea on this? Still stumped. I've posted my question on the developer's page, but no response there either.